# iOS scene based application with Qt

Tags: ios, qt

In order to get started with CarPlay, it seems applications need to make use of the newer "Scenes" mechanism in iOS as opposed to start everything in the ApplicationDelegate.

Now I'm trying to get that down with an existing Qt application. However, Qt for iOS seems to be tied quite closely to the AppDelegate approach. So far my most promising attempt seems to be defining a UIWindowSceneDelegate like this

```
@interface PhoneSceneDelegate : UIResponder <UIWindowSceneDelegate>
@end

@implementation PhoneSceneDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    qWarning() << "willConnectToSession";
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithWindowScene:(UIWindowScene *)scene];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[QIOSViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
@end
```

and listing that in the Info.plist in the `UIApplicationSceneManifest` part.

This seems to switch the application to the scenes mechanism and also calls my code above, however I can't figure out how to instruct Qt to properly create the ViewController and the surface just stays black.

Any pointers how to successfully create a Qt based SceneDelegate?